# how to show all parents treeview item by passing the child name-WPF Treeview

Tags: wpf

Design time we have added the treeview items. During run time, we will the take child items name and I have to show the all parents treeview items in WPF.

To a function I will pass the child treeview item, with this I have to show all parents treeview items. Please help to achieve this.

Comment: Might I recommend you give it a try and let us if you run into any problems? We'd love to help if you hit a snag.

Comment: `show the all parents treeview items` - as you want them to show? In as strings names?